# Redesign output column powershell script for NTFS permission

Tags: powershell, permissions, ntfs

I want to re-design the output column script:

```
$FolderPath = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path "C:\DRIVERS" -Recurse -Depth 2 -Force
$Output = @()
ForEach ($Folder in $FolderPath) 
 {
    $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Folder.FullName
    ForEach ($Access in $Acl.Access)
     {
$Properties = [ordered]@{'Folder Name'=$Folder.FullName;'Group/User'=$Access.IdentityReference;'Permissions'=$Access.FileSystemRights;'Inherited'=$Access.IsInherited;'Real name'=$Access.IdentityReference}
$Output += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties            
}
}
$Output | Out-GridView
```

to be able to instead showing log-on name of the user who have access to also show in another column the Name of the user in AD.
I tried with

```
-ExpandProperty Access | Select-Object @{n='User';e={ (Get-ADUser -Identity $_.IdentityReference.Value.Split("\")[1]).Name }}
```

but didn't fit it quite well.

Comment: Why are you making a call to AD to get ACL on a locally logged-on user? Just call $env:USERNAME PowerShell default to get that, or use a number of other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment. Here are a number of ways to get locally logged on username.

```
$env:UserName

[System.Environment]::UserName

[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name

(Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $(
    Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'explorer.exe'"
) -MethodName GetOwner).User

(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name='explorer.exe'" | 
Select Name, @{
    Name       = 'UserName'
    Expression = {"$($PSItem.GetOwner().Domain)\$($PSItem.GetOwner().User)"}
}).UserName

(Get-Process -Name 'explorer' -IncludeUserName).UserName

(Get-WMIObject -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | 
    Select-Object -Property Username
).username

whoami
```